# I want the creation of a subProject to automatically add an id to the subProjectIds list

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hello I create a Project that when is selected goes at head of subProject. What I want is when add a subProject I want the creation of subProject to automatically add an id to the subProjectIds so the subProjects array should be connected with that selected project, below you can find a code.

This is the interface of Project

```
export interface Project {
id: string;
category: string;
color: number;
name: string;
state: number;
type: number;
level: number;
select: string;
subProjectIds: string[];
}
```

This is the subProject when is saved

```
save() {
  if (this.newSubProjectName.length > 0) {
  this.working = true;
  const newSubProject: SubProject = emptySubProject();
  newSubProject.name = this.newSubProjectName;
  newSubProject.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(1, 2);
  newSubProject.color = this.newSubProjectColor;
  this.store.dispatch(new 
  UpsertSubProjectInternalAction(newSubProject));
  this.newSubProjectName = '';
  }
  }
```

This is when project is selected html

```
 <div class="project clickable" (click)="getProjectName(project)">
```

This is the typescript

```
getProjectName(project) {
this.project = project.name;
console.log('####', project)
}
```

This is line the header of subProject I used like binding.

```
<span>{{project.name}}</span>
```

And this is *ngFor of subProject.

```
<div *ngFor="let subproject of getSubProject()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's for your time @Mitch Wilkins but at .ts just changed this.project = project.name with this.project = project and now is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do here is go with a model class instead of an interface. You can implement models like you can an interface. I would suggest creating a method that generates the ID for the sub project array somehow.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow I have the connection a subProject with Project, but now is not taking the project I select when I save a subProject but takes a random Project without any Id.

Comment: Are you using an *ngFor to generate the projects? How does it know which project you’re clicking on?

Comment: I edited the code i uploaded some extra code when i call *ngFor for subprojects.